# How can i monitor the process using c#?

Tags: c#

I want my application to monitor and Log the Process that are started and terminated in winxp machine during the existence of my application. i dont want to get all the process names that are running. How can i achieve this ? Any ideas appreciated.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void Monitor()
    { 
        ArrayList existingProcesses = GetExistingProcess();  

        while (true)
        {  
            ArrayList currentProcesses = new ArrayList();
            currentProcesses = GetCurrentProcess();

            ArrayList NewApps = new ArrayList(GetCurrentProcess());

            foreach (var p in ExistingProcess)
            {
                NewApps.Remove(p); 
            }
            string str = "";
            foreach (string NewApp in NewApps)
            {
                str = "Process Name : " + NewApp + "   Process ID : " + System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(NewApp)[0].Id.ToString() + " ";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, without hooking into any windows internals would be to poll the list of running processes every so often.

```
using System.Diagnostics;


// Poll every 5 seconds
while(true)
{
    // Get a list of running processes
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    // Do logging
    // ...

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to fetch all the process names. Need the process names that are started and terminated during my thread in application is running.

Comment: @Anuya in this case you need to rephrase your question, because that is not what you asked.

Comment: Rephrased ...Thanks, Now how can do this ?

Comment: @Anuya You can still use the above approach, but keep a copy of the original list. Then, on each poll, compare with the original list to see which processes are new. It might be better to use WMI though, as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can list all process using [`Process.GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx).

You can then monitor each process in the returned process array.